# Qual è il significato di "indugiare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Il sole era ancora basso sull'orizzonte e un po' annebbiato. Si vedeva solo la sommità delle colline di fronte, perchè la base era cancellata dalla nebbia che **indugiava** nel fondovalle. Un luccicore sinuoso indicava il corso del fiume.

La mia domanda è sul significato del verbo "indugiare" nel brano precedente. Ho cercato questo vocabolo nel [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/indugiare/), ma non ho saputo trovare in modo esplicito nessuna accezione in senso figurato che corrisponda alla citazione di sopra. Ho cercato di immaginare il significato della frase, ma non sono sicura di aver capito il senso corretto. Significa che la nebbia tardava a sparire del fondovalle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Indugiare* significa *trattenersi* (in un luogo), quindi, proprio come hai immaginato, significa che la nebbia restava nel fondovalle, non si alzava dissolvendosi.